# Can't access Schema variables in Mongoose through static method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, enums, mongoose-schema

I am working through a tutorial, building a small library DB in Express and Mongoose.  In the tutorial each book can have one of several statuses, and only one of those values.  It's an Enum.  I am handling this by putting an array of values in the BookInstance schema:

```
var the_statuses = ['Available', 'Maintenance', 'Loaned', 'Reserved'];
```

which works fine when I have an instance -- I use a virtual method to fetch those values

```
BookInstanceSchema
    .virtual('statuses')
    .get(function() {
      return the_statuses;
    });
```

when I, as said, have an instance already.

And when creating the Schema I access my local variable as, well, a local variable:

```
var BookInstanceSchema = Schema({
  book: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Book', required: true }, //reference to the associated book
  imprint: {type: String, required: true},
  status: {type: String, required: true, enum: the_statuses, default: 'Maintenance'},
  due_back: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

But what if I want to simply get the enum values directly from the schema but from *outside* the schema?  That is, if I want to *create*, in this case, a BookInstance instance, and offer the user a choice of statuses in a select menu, I won't have access to an instance yet (unless I kludge it and simply create one to grab the enum values).

I tried making a static function

```
BookInstanceSchema.statics.getStatuses = function() {
    return this.the_statuses;
};
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

What's the best way to do what I'm trying to do?  Is there such a thing as a "static virtual method" in Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a little bit since I have used MongoDB (and Mongoose, obviously), but `static` methods don't have access to instances. Thus, you really shouldn't be using `this` inside a static method. Additionally, it doesn't appear that an instance of `BookInstanceSchema` has a property `the_statuses` (just the virtual `statuses`). Judging from your code, it looks like you would have access to the `the_statuses` variable in your `BookInstanceSchema` definition. So, why not use it directly?

```
BookInstanceSchema.statics.getStatuses = function() {
    return the_statuses;
};

// Use like
BookInstanceSchema.getStatuses();
```

EDIT:

For more general information on `this` in JavaScript, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), and [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). In brief, it's behavior changes when in "strict" mode, and it can be manipulated by the Function class's methods `.call` and `.apply`, to name a few of the oddities.

You'd be right to assume that `this` would refer to the object with which a given method was called, as that is default behavior. In our case, that object would be `BookInstanceSchema.statics`. But, there's the case that Mongoose calls any method under `statics` in a different context (i'm assuming here), like `BookInstanceSchema`, but it certainly does not call from the context of an instance, that's the context that methods on `BookInstanceSchema.methods` would be called in. It needs to be noted that this is completely non-standard. Mongoose is essentially mimicking OOP concepts like Class Methods, and Instance Methods (`Schema.statics` and `Schema.methods`, respectively). In the case of Mongoose, i'm not sure which object `this` refers to in methods on `Schema.statics`, but it definitely refers to the instance object on `Schema.methods`.

As the "class" syntax gets older (brought forth in ES2015) more libraries will probably accommodate a more "standard" way to define Class Methods and Instance Methods ([Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html) is working on this in their next release). Additionally, OOP concepts like Class Methods and Instance Methods are achievable in JS, albeit a little differently. if you're interested, [this article](https://javascript.info/class) will shed a lot of light on how that works in Vanilla JS, along with great examples of the new class syntax contrasted with the older function-prototype syntax.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Although I've programmed a long time, it's been in other languages and the "this" of Javascript sometimes throws me.  In this context, one must be inside an instance to refer to 'this'?  As I understand it, 'this' refers to the object/code structure from which a function is called -- but if you call a static method in Mongoose, it's being called _from_ something?  I think I may be mixing and matching OOP -- which is what I'm used to -- and the Javascript world, but I'm keen to understand _why_ your solution worked.  But anyway, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Yeah, `this` is very weird in JS, even more so in the context of Mongoose. Will edit the answer with some details.